# squid apply rules to a some users

Tags: squid, access-control-list, rules, linux

Good day:

I have a squid 2.7 stable9 installation that works. It is connected to LDAP and the users can authenticate perfectly. I have different rules for instance to block a few websites during working hours. Now I want to make some special users like my boss, to be able to access that websites during working hours. I can do it by mac address. But he needs to be able to access from different computers so the mac address rule is not practical. I need to be able to block depending on the user names.
For instance I have tried this:

```
acl SpecialUser ident abel pedro geronimo
http_access allow SpecialUser
http_access allow password localnet MorningWork !denySite
http_access allow password localnet AfternoonWork !denySite
http_access allow password localnet !MorningWork !AfternoonWork
http_access deny all
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?
Regards and thank you